# Excel Sumifs with multiple criteria with OR

Tags: excel-formula, sum, sumifs

This has been driving me crazy all morning. Can someone help me please figure out how to use this sumifs with an OR?

Here is my formula:

```
=SUMIFS($H2:$H802,$A2:$A802, "COMPLETED ORDER",$B2:$B802, "Joe Johnson",$C2:$C802, "1/1/2018")
```

The formula seems to work the way it is, but what if I want the formula to choose either: COMPLETED ORDER OR (alternatively) CONFIRMATION RECEIVED?

Comment: Please edit your question to either excel or google. As Scott said below, formulas work differently with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use data validation to control the contents of a cell (I used E2 on the sheet) with the two conditions and just reference E2 in your existing formula instead of the text "completed order" etc.

You can either build the list directly in the data validation or you can reference a list on the sheet. You could also use this for the list of names that you want to work with...

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I would upvote you but the previous person downvoted me and took away that ability.

Comment: I’ve voted up the question - maybe that will help, you can always accept the answer with the “tick” box as well, best of luck anyway..

Comment: Thank you so much!